# What is the secure way to store database connection string information that can be created at run-time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection

I am creating a web application that allows the user to choose and save which database he/she wants to connect to in order to set that as the database that contains users information.

STEP 1: Create database connection setting with a) database engine, b) host, c) port, d) username, e) password

STEP 2: Choose this database setting as being the one that will be used in order to connect ot the database to view user information

STEP 3: View sets of users based on filters and rules

My question is what is the secure way to store dynamically created "connection strings?"

*NOTE: I don't want to have hard-coded connection strings in a config file because I want the users to be able to configure their own at run-time and then use them without having to have an admin mess with updating files on the server.

**NOTE AGAIN: I also want a user to be able to use different connection strings at different times while using the web application. First they may want to use the connection to DB1 but then 5 minutes later they may need to use the connection to DB2.

Comment: Why don't you make another database that holds all of you connection strings and then have the connection string to that one hard coded? Then you can update and insert the connection strings real time, and also they are saved there so they can be used again in the indefinite future.

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now but I'm unsure if that's the secure way to do it.

Comment: I think you need to narrow it down - there are many possibilities you can choose from. What do you mean by *secure*?

Comment: I mean in a way that IT guys won't freak out because I'm storing sensitive db connection strings in a database.